# Initial instal of Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I have been given a PC operating Windowsxp. Browsing with Maxathon as Internet explorer and Google chrome not supported. I desire to run Ubuntu to replace my OS and have downloaded the file Ubuntu. I cannot open this file. Basic question but cannot find solution through google or in help article. Cannot open ISO file.
Help!

Comment: Does this help?     https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview    If not please [edit] your question and describe what goes wrong.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview   You have provided no details on what Ubuntu you have downloaded and ready for install. Ubuntu comes available in various releases, plus ISOs for desktops, servers, appliances and more. It's available in different architectures (many of which won't be usable on your machine).  You've provided no specs as to your machine, but I'd likely use a *flavor* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of Ubuntu. I used machines as old as from 2003 (ie. XP era) to QA-test *flavors* of 18.04; but I'd not use main Ubuntu on them.

Comment: Ubuntu computer minimum spec's: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#1-overview
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/14022

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to boot the 'ISO' file so if you have downloaded it on to the machine you will need to copy it to either a CDROM that you can boot from or other media that the computer can boot from.

The instructions for [creating a bootable usb drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) might be the easiest way of getting Ubuntu on that machine.